# How to put a label as link at the end of coloumns in a subform (Datasheet) in Access 2000?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a database created in access 2000. A form with a subform (datasheet - defaultview) in it. I have added a label at end of the coloumns in subform and given hyperlink to open the object present in database itself. But when the form open nothing is visible after the coloumn ? I got four coloumns and had hide two columns via onload event of subform. the code is below

```
Me.SubGroupname.ColumnHidden = True
Me.GroupName.ColumnHidden = True
Me.BNFno.ColumnHidden = False
Me.BNFno.ColumnWidth = -2
Me.SubGroupName1.ColumnWidth = -2
```

How can I make it visible so that it will appear as a link at each row ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you cannot use Datasheet view to display a control at the end of a row. Switch to Continuous Forms view, it will give you more control, but you will have to work a little harder to get a nice layout.

Alternatively, add a click event to one of the existing columns.

Comment: so datasheet view only display coloumns ? no other elements cant bind at end right ?

Comment: A datasheet can show a hyperlink in a column.  You can create a hyperlink to open an Access object in the current database.